# No .git file uploaded on Git Repository

Tags: git, github

I have done git init and created a Git Repository for my project. When I "cd .git" I enter the folder. But my problem is that in the Git Repository the .git file does not get uploaded. I tried changing directory and doing a fresh git init, but the problem persists. As a result when someone clones my Repository, there is no .git folder and hence it says not a Git repository.

Comment: How did you upload the git repository?

Comment: via VCS import in Android Studio. I did a git status and pushed some commits as well, but the .git file is not on the repo. Link: https://github.com/JaiKotia/NewsMap

Comment: Post content of .git/config file

Comment: @SumitMahamuni here: [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = true
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true

Comment: @JaiKotia, the `.git/` directory won't show up in GitHub's UI. Why do you want to see it there? (Note that the `.git/` directory is not tracked content: your `.git/` and GitHub's will be different.)

Comment: @Chris are we sure the OP is using github?

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, not sure since the question isn't very clear. But it's tagged with [tag:github].

Comment: @chris that certainly would suggest its use. Only thing I don't understand... how can someone clone a repo and _not_ have the .git folder?

Comment: Did they actually clone the repo or just download it as a zip?

Comment: @jdno downloaded as zip. But isn't that option under "Clone" when you visit the repo on a website. It should be the same as "git clone" in terminal right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On GitHub, you can either clone the repository or download it as a `.zip` file. When you decide to download the directory, GitHub exports only the files you can see in GitHub's file browser, and it does not set it up as a Git repository. This is why there is no `.git` folder, and why Git commands don't work in the extracted directory.

Downloading a repository as a `.zip` file can be really useful when you don't care about the history and don't want to make any changes to the code. But when you want to collaborate, you need to properly clone the repository. If cloning the repository on the CLI is too complicated, check out the graphical UIs that exist for Git (e.g. GitHub Desktop, GitKraken, SourceTree just to name a few).

Answer (score 6):

The `.git` folder never gets added/committed/pushed/uploaded. That's perfectly normal and not a problem at all. The `.git` folder manages your local copy of your repository. Your repository on GitHub has its' own `.git` folder, as has anyone cloning your repository. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928684/7598462) for a detailed explanation of what the folder contains.

The question that persists is why a person cloning your repository does get the `not a Git repository` message. Did they `cd` into the repository folder after cloning?

Comment: Yes I did cd into thier repository folder, but there was no .git folder. That's what confuses me. Command terminal also says "Not a git repository".

Comment: So they cloned the repo using `git clone`, all files where copied in the latest version, but the whole thing is no git repository?!

Comment: My bad, I assumed downloading file as .zip would set up a working git repository. Seems like git clone is the correct approach